# How set search php code behind custom search box in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, search-box

I am building this search box in custom coding but I want to implement it in Wordpress format code. I have set this on right place and all is ok. But now how do I make it functional in Wordpress CMS? I am sharing code please let me know how I can make it functional.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 remove-space" id="core_header_searchbox">
     <form action="http://abcchasma.com/market/" method="get" id="wlt_searchbox_form">
         <div class="wlt_searchbox clearfix">
             <div class="inner">
                 <div class="wlt_button_search">
                     Search
                 </div>
                 <input type="text" style="width: 320px;height: 40px;font-weight: 100;padding: 5px;" name="s" placeholder="Please search here" value="">
             </div>
         </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form action as follows

```
<form action="/" method="get">
```

I do this exact thing on my [news page](https://trulaw.com/news) - right sidebar at the bottom:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" id="search" placeholder="Search for..." value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
</form>
```

Comment: it says "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Answer (score 0):

The `form` action need to be pointed to the home url of your WP site. If your website is placed in the document root, you can just use a slash as action:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
```

A flexible alternative (and more appropriate) can be to call a function which returns the right url of the website:

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" method="get">
```